# A durable rubber type material that can flex easily but return to its original shape very fast

Tags: polymers, materials, rubber

I'm looking for a durable rubber type of material for a guitar pick holder. The material I'm looking for will need to have flexibility to pick individual notes of a guitar, but needs to return to its original shape/position as fast as possible for picking faster notes.

I've tried vulcanized rubber sheets of different thicknesses (1 mm to 4 mm), it has good flexibility, but returning to its original shape is very slow.

The material from a bouncy ball is the closest material I can imagine for what I need, but I need something in a sheet form.

Comment: I think this question is better asked on the Music (or Engineering) stackexchange since this question isn't about Chemistry.

Comment: I think "rubber type" and "very fast return" exclude each other. It would need some hard flexible plastics or metal. The softer and more compressible material is (like rubber), the weaker are the forces returning it to its original shape, causing slow return.